# OpenCV: Is possible to open Compressed Video in Java?

Tags: java, file, opencv, file-processing

I have compressed .avi format video. I want to get frames from Video using OpenCV.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
    String filePath = "C:\\Users\\P6090053.avi";
    String output = "C:\\Users\\Test";

    if (!Paths.get(filePath).toFile().exists()) {
       System.out.println("File " + filePath + " does not exist!");
       return;
    }
   VideoCapture video = new VideoCapture(filePath);

   video.open(filePath);/*Cant open compressed video*/

   System.out.println(video.isOpened()); /*Always returns **false***/
}
```

Whereas with above code i can open uncompressed video but i cannot open compressed video of Format "Microsoft RLE".

**Video Info: FileExtension:"avi", Format:"RLE", CodecID: "0*01000000"**

Sample video : http://www.engr.colostate.edu/me/facil/dynamics/avis.htm
(download bird.avi - **Format - Indeo4**)

Thanks in advance:)

Comment: Info: May help someone: I used Xuggler for processing video to frames: https://github.com/artclarke/xuggle-xuggler/blob/master/src/com/xuggle/xuggler/demos/DecodeAndCaptureFrames.java

Answer (score 0):

Use `FFmpegFrameGrabber` in package `org.bytedeco.javacv`.

For example:

```
FFmpegFrameGrabber grabber = new FFmpegFrameGrabber(file);

grabber.start();
grabber.setFrameNumber(1000);

Java2DFrameConverter paintConverter = new Java2DFrameConverter();

ImageIO.write(paintConverter.getBufferedImage(grabber.grabKeyFrame(), 1), "jpg", new FileOutputStream("somewhere"));
```

You need a couple of dependencies, OpenCV itself, FFmpeg and a native library of FFmpeg (or all native libraries).  The Maven example below includes the Windows native library.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.bytedeco</groupId>
  <artifactId>javacv</artifactId>
  <version>1.4.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets</groupId>
  <artifactId>ffmpeg</artifactId>
  <version>3.4.2-1.4.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets</groupId>
  <artifactId>ffmpeg</artifactId>
  <version>3.4.2-1.4.1</version>
  <classifier>windows-x86_64</classifier>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I realised you're using opencv, disregard this answer if it is not an option to use javacv (which uses opencv)

Comment: I tried FFmpeg now, but i am getting " java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.bytedeco.ffmpeg.global.avutil" error. I google it but no help. I downloaded comple bytedeco jar and added to project. But i dono what i am really missing:(

Comment: Updated answer with required Maven dependencies.  Sounds like you are missing the ffmpeg jar.

Comment: Unfortuantly i am not using Maven:( I am tring to download dependices from Maven repo but still same error

Comment: JavaCV has a dozen dependencies.  I'd recommend using a dependency management system if you are going to use it.

Comment: I have a question: javacv process compressed video?john

Comment: Sure it does, I've processed over 5000 videos with it to grab sample frames.